# How do I read JSON string from a text file parse it?

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

```
{ 
    'username': ['kat']
    'email': ['abc']
}
```

I saved this as `file.js`.
When I read it and parse it, I am getting error:

> a SyntaxError Unexpected token

```
fs.readFile('./file.js', 'utf8',
    function(err, data){
        console.log(data); //OK
        data = JSON.parse(data);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JSON uses double quotes, not single quotes. Also, you need a comma after `['kat']`:

```
{
  "username": ["kat"],
  "email": ["abc"]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is because your json is not valid. Your json should be as follow:

```
{
"Hello": [
    {
        "username": "kat"
    },
    {
        "email": "abc"
    }
]
}
```

And it is better practise to read file from `.json` file extension. `js` extension is used for javascript files

Comment: That JSON is not equivalent to the OP's JSON.

Answer (score 0):

Invalid JSON should be:

```
{ 
    "username": ["kat"],
    "email": ["abc"]
}
```